# Getting an Undefined Offset Notice with a script

Tags: php

I am using PHP 5.6. When attempting to use a script, I get an error as such. The script is for sending emails, here is a copy of it. I need assistance fixing it. THANKS. The error is also below:

---

> Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\Apache\htdocs\~spamsite\email.php on line 36

Here is the script:

```html
<?php 

if( isset($_POST['submit'])) 
{
//define the receiver of the email 
    $to = $_POST["to"]; 
//define from whom the email is from ie Name & E-Mail.
    $name=$_POST["name"];
    $from = $_POST["from"]; 
//define who will be copied.
    $cc = $_POST["cc"];
//define who will be blind copied.
    $bcc = $_POST["bcc"];
//define the subject of the email 
    $subject = $_POST["subject"]; 
//define the message of the email 
    $message=$_POST["message"]; 
//so we use the MD5 algorithm to generate a random hash 
    $random_hash = md5(date('r', time())); 
//define the headers we want passed. Note that they are separated with \r\n 
    $headers  = "From: " . $name . "<" . $from . ">" . "\nCc: " . $cc . "\nBcc: " . $bcc;
// boundary 
    $semi_rand = md5(time()); 
    $mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x"; 

// headers for attachment  
    $headers .= "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n" . "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n" . " boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\""; 

// multipart boundary 
    $message = "--{$mime_boundary}\n" . "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"UTF-8\"\n" .
    "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" . "<p>" . $message . "</p>" . "\n\n"; 
 
// Preparing Attachment.
    for($i=0;$i<(count($_FILES["attachment"]["name"])+1);$i++)
    {
        if($_FILES["attachment"]["name"][$i] != "")
        {
            $filename = $_FILES["attachment"]["name"][$i];
            $filetype = $_FILES["attachment"]["type"][$i];
            $content  = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($_FILES["attachment"]["tmp_name"][$i]))); 
            $message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n";
            $message .= "Content-Type: " . $filetype . "; name=\"".$filename."\"\n"; 
            $message .= "Content-Description: " .$filename . "\n";
            $message .= "Content-Disposition: attachment;\n" . " filename=\"".$filename."\";\n";
            $message .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" . $content."\n\n";
        }
            
    }
    $message .= "--{$mime_boundary}--\r\n";
    
//send email
    $mail = @mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers, "-f$from"); 
    
//if the message is sent successfully print "Mail sent". Otherwise print "Mail failed" 
    echo $mail? "Your Mail Has Been Sent Successfully" : "Oops..Something Went Wrong.. Your Mail Has Not Been Sent"; 
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <title>Email Sender</title>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
var upload_number = 2;
function addFileInput() {
     var d = document.createElement("div");
     var file = document.createElement("input");
     file.setAttribute("type", "file");
     file.setAttribute("name", "attachment["+upload_number+"]");
    file.setAttribute("id", "attachment["+upload_number+"]");
    file.setAttribute("size", "30")
     d.appendChild(file);
     document.getElementById("moreUploads").appendChild(d);
     upload_number++;
}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://js.nicedit.com/nicEdit-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
        bkLib.onDomLoaded(function() 
        {
             new nicEditor({fullPanel : true}).panelInstance('message'); 
        });
  //]]>
  </script>
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<table width="1321" height="70" border="0">
  <tr>
    <td width="1298">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>

   <table width="1321" border="1"><tbody>
   <tr>
     <td width="132">To [Direct]:</td>
     <td width="1142" bgcolor="#CC0000"><input name="to" type="text" size="100" /> 
      <strong>Separate with Commas &quot;,&quot; While Sending to Many</strong></td></tr>
     <tr>
       <td width="132">To [Cc] :</td>
   <td width="1142" bgcolor="#CC0000"><input name="cc" type="text" size="100" /> 
     <strong>Separate with Commas &quot;,&quot; While Copying to Many</strong></td></tr>
     <tr>
       <td width="132">To [Bcc] :</td>
   <td width="1142" bgcolor="#CC0000"><input name="bcc" type="text" size="100" /> 
     <strong>Separate with Commas &quot;,&quot; While Blind Copying to Many</strong></td></tr>
   <tr>
     <td>From [Email]:</td><td><input name="from" type="text" size="100" /></td></tr>
   <tr>
     <td>From [Name] :</td><td><input name="name" type="text" size="100"/></td></tr>
   <tr><td>Subject :</td><td><input name="subject" type="text" size="100"/></td></tr>
   <tr><td>Message :</td><td><textarea cols="120" rows="15" name="message" id="message"></textarea>
   </td></tr>
   <tr>
     <td>Add Attachment:</td><td>
     <input type="file" name="attachment[]" id="attachment[]"  size="30" onchange="document.getElementById('moreUploadsLink').style.display = 'block';" />
<div id="moreUploads"></div>
<div id="moreUploadsLink" style="display:none;"><a href="java-script:addFileInput();">Attach another File</a></div>
     </td></tr></td></tr>
   <tr>
     <td height="28"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" /></td></tr>
   </tbody></table>
</form>
```

Comment: Which one is your line 36...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What it looks like you have an error in your for loop:

Try this:

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES["attachment"]["name"]); $i++)
```

Instead of:

```
for($i=0;$i<(count($_FILES["attachment"]["name"])+1);$i++)
```

Because if you have 3 files attached then there will be:

```
$_FILES["attachment"]["name"][0]
$_FILES["attachment"]["name"][1]
$_FILES["attachment"]["name"][2]
```

And your `count($_FILES["attachment"]["name"])` will return 3. And you only wanna go up to 2.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not sure whether or not array contains certain key you should use

```
if(isset($array['key'])) {
    //Do something
}
```

It seems that you should change this line

```
 for($i=0;$i<(count($_FILES["attachment"]["name"])+1);$i++)
```

to

```
if(isset($_FILES["attachment"]) && isset($_FILES["attachment"]["name"]))
    for($i=0;$i<(count($_FILES["attachment"]["name"])+1);$i++)
```